# How do I count groups of 3 tied to a name in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr

Say I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

name1 <- c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary","Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe",  "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David")

name2 <- c("Mary", "Thomas", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Carl", "Joel", "Victoria", "Elaine", "Cory", "June", "John", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Holly", "Michael", "Dwight", "Jim", "Andy", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Helen", "Lauren", "Bill", "Saul", "Ben", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "David", "Robert", "Holly", "Michael", "James", "Renee", "Sally", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "Paul", "Joe", "Peter", "Clark", "Elaine", "Cory", "Victoria")

df <- data.frame(name1, name2)
```

I want to be able to count the number of times each value in "name1" has the same 3 values in "name2". For example, John (name1) has Linda, David, and Joe (name2) and Mary (name 1) also has Linda, David, and Joe (name2). So if we only to look at John and Mary, the number of times all 3 names are in one group is 2. I'd like to produce a table that shows the number of times three names appears in name2 for a name in name1.

I know how I would write the function for pairs:

```
count_pairs <- 
  function(df) {
    df %>%
      apply(1, sort) %>%
      t() %>%
      data.frame() %>%
      group_by_all() %>%
      count(name = "Occurrences_Pair")
  }

df_pairs <- df %>% count_pairs()
```

But how would I do it for groups of 3, 4, 5, etc.?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think there's some confusion about what exactly you are asking. Is the number `3` counting the size of the overlap between *pairs* of `name2` sets each defined by a unique `name1` **OR** are you interested in comparing larger numbers of `name1` sets (greater than 2) **OR** something else?

Answer (score 3):

```r
count_groups_of <- function(df, n) {
  varname <- as.symbol(paste0('combs_of_', n))
  df %>% 
    group_by(name1) %>% 
    summarise(!!varname := combn(name2, n, function(x) toString(sort(x))), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    group_by(!!varname) %>% 
    summarise(n = n(), which_name1 = toString(name1), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    arrange(-n)
}

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>% 
  count_groups_of(3)
#> # A tibble: 556 × 3
#>    combs_of_3                 n which_name1      
#>    <chr>                  <int> <chr>            
#>  1 David, Joe, Linda          3 Anne, John, Mary 
#>  2 David, John, Linda         3 Anne, Joe, Mary  
#>  3 David, Linda, Mary         3 Anne, Joe, John  
#>  4 Joe, John, Linda           3 Anne, David, Mary
#>  5 Joe, Linda, Mary           3 Anne, David, John
#>  6 John, Linda, Mary          3 Anne, David, Joe 
#>  7 Cory, Elaine, Joe          2 David, John      
#>  8 Cory, Elaine, Linda        2 David, John      
#>  9 Cory, Elaine, Mary         2 David, John      
#> 10 Cory, Elaine, Victoria     2 David, John      
#> # … with 546 more rows

df %>% 
  count_groups_of(4)
#> # A tibble: 1,026 × 3
#>    combs_of_4                        n which_name1
#>    <chr>                         <int> <chr>      
#>  1 Cory, Elaine, Joe, Linda          2 David, John
#>  2 Cory, Elaine, Joe, Mary           2 David, John
#>  3 Cory, Elaine, Joe, Victoria       2 David, John
#>  4 Cory, Elaine, Linda, Mary         2 David, John
#>  5 Cory, Elaine, Linda, Victoria     2 David, John
#>  6 Cory, Elaine, Mary, Victoria      2 David, John
#>  7 Cory, Joe, Linda, Mary            2 David, John
#>  8 Cory, Joe, Linda, Victoria        2 David, John
#>  9 Cory, Joe, Mary, Victoria         2 David, John
#> 10 Cory, Linda, Mary, Victoria       2 David, John
#> # … with 1,016 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Error in `:=`(!!varname, combn(name2, n, toString)) : 
could not find function ":="`

Comment: I think that may be because you're running an old version of `dplyr`. I have `1.0.7`. You can see what version you have with `sessionInfo()$otherPkgs$dplyr`, and install a new version with `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: Sort the combinations before collapsing to a string for the results to be correct.

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento, I just assumed `combn` produced combination vectors whose elements are sorted already, but was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`. This says, for instance, that John and Mary share 3 names, while John and David share 6.

First I join all rows with other rows matching on `name2`, then filter out matching `name1` (all will match 100% with themselves), keep distinct matches, and count how many between each name1 and another.

```
left_join(mutate(df, val = 1),
          mutate(df, val = 1), by = c("val", "name2")) %>%
  filter(name1.x != name1.y) %>%
  distinct(name2, name1.x, name1.y) %>%
  count(name1.x, name1.y) %>%
  arrange(n)
```

Result

```
   name1.x name1.y n
1    David     Joe 3
2    David    Mary 3
3      Joe   David 3
4      Joe    John 3
5     John     Joe 3
6     John    Mary 3
7     Mary   David 3
8     Mary    John 3
9     Anne   David 4
10    Anne     Joe 4
11    Anne    John 4
12    Anne    Mary 4
13   David    Anne 4
14     Joe    Anne 4
15    John    Anne 4
16    Mary    Anne 4
17     Joe    Mary 5
18    Mary     Joe 5
19   David    John 6
20    John   David 6
```

or replace the last line with the lines below to produce a coincidence table:

```
complete(name1.x, name1.y, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%  # skip if order doesn't matter
pivot_wider(names_from = name1.y, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  name1.x  Anne David   Joe  John  Mary
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Anne        0     4     4     4     4
2 David       4     0     3     6     3
3 Joe         4     3     0     3     5
4 John        4     6     3     0     3
5 Mary        4     3     5     3     0
```

Comment: When I use the dplyr solution, I get `Error in count(., name1.x, name1.y) : object 'name1.x' not found`

Comment: Hmm, works fine for me using dplyr 1.0.7. What columns do you have after running just through the `distinct` line?

Answer (score 2):

Here comes a fast solution using `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral`.

```
nm <- sort(unique(df$name2)) ## unique names
M <- matrix(df$name2, 10)  ## make a matrix, nrow acc. to name 1 groups

f <- \(n) RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(
  nm, n, FUN=\(x) c(x, n=sum(colSums(array(M %in% x, dim=dim(M))) == n))) |>
  do.call(what=rbind) |> as.data.frame() |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |>
  (\(.) .[order(-.$n), ])() |> `rownames<-`(NULL)
```

### Gives

```
head(f(2))
#      V1    V2 n
# 1 David Linda 4
# 2   Joe Linda 4
# 3  John Linda 4
# 4 Linda  Mary 4
# 5 David   Joe 3
# 6 David  John 3
head(f(3))
#      V1    V2    V3 n
# 1 David   Joe Linda 3
# 2 David  John Linda 3
# 3 David Linda  Mary 3
# 4   Joe  John Linda 3
# 5   Joe Linda  Mary 3
# 6  John Linda  Mary 3
head(f(4))
#     V1     V2    V3       V4 n
# 1 Cory Elaine   Joe    Linda 2
# 2 Cory Elaine   Joe     Mary 2
# 3 Cory Elaine   Joe Victoria 2
# 4 Cory Elaine Linda     Mary 2
# 5 Cory Elaine Linda Victoria 2
# 6 Cory Elaine  Mary Victoria 2
head(f(5))
#      V1     V2    V3    V4       V5 n
# 1  Cory Elaine   Joe Linda     Mary 2
# 2  Cory Elaine   Joe Linda Victoria 2
# 3  Cory Elaine   Joe  Mary Victoria 2
# 4  Cory Elaine Linda  Mary Victoria 2
# 5  Cory    Joe Linda  Mary Victoria 2
# 6 David  Holly  John Linda  Michael 2
head(f(6))
#     V1     V2     V3    V4   V5       V6 n
# 1 Cory Elaine    Joe Linda Mary Victoria 2
# 2 Andy  David Dwight Holly  Jim      Joe 1
# 3 Andy  David Dwight Holly  Jim     John 1
# 4 Andy  David Dwight Holly  Jim     June 1
# 5 Andy  David Dwight Holly  Jim    Linda 1
# 6 Andy  David Dwight Holly  Jim  Michael 1
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(name1 = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", 
"John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", 
"Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Anne", 
"Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", 
"Anne", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", 
"Joe", "Joe", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", 
"David", "David", "David", "David"), name2 = c("Mary", "Thomas", 
"Linda", "David", "Joe", "Carl", "Joel", "Victoria", "Elaine", 
"Cory", "June", "John", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Holly", "Michael", 
"Dwight", "Jim", "Andy", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "David", "Joe", 
"Helen", "Lauren", "Bill", "Saul", "Ben", "Mary", "John", "Linda", 
"David", "Robert", "Holly", "Michael", "James", "Renee", "Sally", 
"Mary", "John", "Linda", "Paul", "Joe", "Peter", "Clark", "Elaine", 
"Cory", "Victoria")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `intersect()` to report the overlap of each pairwise combination of `name1` values and reports the size and contents of the overlap.

```r
library(tidyverse)

name1 <- c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary","Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Anne", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe",  "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David", "David")

name2 <- c("Mary", "Thomas", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Carl", "Joel", "Victoria", "Elaine", "Cory", "June", "John", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Holly", "Michael", "Dwight", "Jim", "Andy", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "David", "Joe", "Helen", "Lauren", "Bill", "Saul", "Ben", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "David", "Robert", "Holly", "Michael", "James", "Renee", "Sally", "Mary", "John", "Linda", "Paul", "Joe", "Peter", "Clark", "Elaine", "Cory", "Victoria")

df <- data.frame(name1, name2)

df %>%
  group_by(name1) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  set_names(unique(name1)) %>%
  map(., ~ pull(.x, name2)) %>%
  combn(., 2, function(x)
    intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = F) %>%
  set_names(combn(unique(df$name1), 2, function(x) {
    paste(x[[1]], x[[2]], sep = "_")
  })) %>%
  map_dfc(., ~ toString(.x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "combo_names", values_to = "intersection") %>%
  separate(combo_names,
           into = c("name_a", "name_b"),
           sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(intersection_size = str_count(intersection, ", ") + 1, .after = name_b) %>% 
  arrange(intersection_size)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    name_a name_b intersection_size intersection                            
#>    <chr>  <chr>              <dbl> <chr>                                   
#>  1 Mary   Anne                   3 Mary, John, Linda                       
#>  2 Mary   David                  3 John, Linda, Joe                        
#>  3 Anne   Joe                    3 Mary, Linda, David                      
#>  4 Joe    David                  3 Linda, David, Joe                       
#>  5 John   Mary                   4 Mary, John, Linda, Joe                  
#>  6 John   Anne                   4 Mary, John, Linda, David                
#>  7 John   Joe                    4 Mary, Linda, David, Joe                 
#>  8 John   David                  4 John, Linda, David, Joe                 
#>  9 Anne   David                  5 John, Linda, David, Holly, Michael      
#> 10 Mary   Joe                    6 Mary, Linda, Joe, Elaine, Cory, Victoria
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>